# Compiler Understanding - assign in a if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, assign

I recently came across this syntax

```
int i;
String s = "test";
if(!((i=s.length()) == 0)) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

If you are wondering what it prints it prints:

```
4
```

Now I know this code compiles as well as runs correctly. I also understand that this puts the value of s.length into i. I want to know how is this possible ? 
How can we equate/assign a variable in an if clause. Does some one have any insight not how this work with the compiler

Comment: In C, Java, and a number of other languages an assignment such as `a = 5;` is regarded as an "expression" and hence has a value.  You occasionally see, eg, `a = b = c = 5;` to initialize a bunch of variables to the same value.

Comment: And in some environments you will see something like `while (GOOD_RETURN_CODE == returnCode = someFunction(someParms)) { ...`, so the returnCode of `someFunction` can be saved and checked in one operation.  For `while` statements this avoids some awkward code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An assignment expression

```
i=s.length()
```

resolves to the value being assigned.

[From the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)

> At run time, **the result of the assignment expression is the value of
>   the variable after the assignment has occurred.** The result of an
>   assignment expression is not itself a variable.

I don't want to go get the byte code right now, but basically

1. the value of of `s` is pushed on the stack
2. that value is popped and dereferenced to invoke `String#length()`
3. the result is pushed on the stack
4. the same result is pushed on the stack again
5. that value is popped from the stack and stored in `i`
6. the value of 0 (possibly not as there might be a byte code instruction for comparison with 0) is pushed on the stack
7. the value and 0 are both popped from the stack and compared, with a jump instruction depending on the result

Comment: Does operator precedence have anything to do in this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26152736/1085186

Comment: @wrongAnswer I think SLaks was referring to your comment. In your question, the parentheses explicitly declare the grouping of expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

To understand this, let's try to dissect it, statement per statement

```
if(!((i=s.length()) == 0))
s.length() //results to 4;
i=s.length() //assigned i=4
i=s.length() == 0 //false
!i=s.length() == 0 //invert, becomes true
if(true) {
    //prints i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator is a ordinary expression.
Like any other expression, you can put it wherever you want to.

The value of this expression is the value being assigned.  (This is also why you can write `a = b = c`)

Comment: I knew about a= b =c but this is more like a=b==c now does this mean a==c or b==c ? cause a is not assigned in this case prior to a=b ...

Comment: @wrongAnswer: `==` has a higher precedence than `=`, so that is parsed as `a = (b == c)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Appreciate it never though about operator precedence will read more.

Comment: @Pshemo: I meant ordinary.

Answer (score 1):

The result of a Java assignment is the value assigned, that means this

```
(!((i=s.length()) == 0))
```

Assigns `s.length()` to `i`, and then checks that that value (`s.length()`) is NOT `0`.

Comment: I understand that part what I'm having difficult understanding is how does it know what to compare to ? cause i not initialize.

Comment: @wrongAnswer `i` is initialized to `s.length()` by `i=s.length()`.

Comment: Note that, although it would be equivalent in this case, `i` is not being re-evaluated for the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Java compiler operates on sort of a stack parser where it evaluates from left to right each line. Whenever it encounters a right parenthesis the previous statement back to the last left parenthesis will be executed before anything else so...

The inner-most parenthesis will be evaluated before anything else which is of course (i=s.length()).

I'm not at my main computer right now so I can't really test this but I'm sure you'd receive a syntax error if you remove the parentheses around i=s.length().